# Trigger is not getting Fired on After Insert

Tags: apex, trigger, event

I have a Custom Object as TUC object .When i create a record in TUC obj , it should automatically create a record in Event and Task.But the trigger written is not getting fired .Any help is very much appreciated.

Here is the Code :

```
trigger CreateEvent on TUC__c(after insert){
   List<Event> eventList = new List<Event>();
   for(TUC__c tucObj : Trigger.new){
      Event event = new Event();
      event.whatid  = tucObj.Account_Related__c;  
      event.Subject = tucObj.subject__c;
      event.OwnerId = tucObj.CreatedById;
      event.StartDateTime = tucObj.Start_Date__c;
      event.EndDateTime=tucObj.End_Date__c;
      eventList.add(event);
   }
   if(eventList.size()>0 && eventlist!==null){
      insert eventList;
   }
}
```

Comment: change your `if` condition second part into `eventList != null` and try

Comment: `if (eventList.size()>0 && eventlist !=null)` will not handle nulls. If `eventlist` is ever null (and it never will be in your case) then you will get a NPE error on `eventList.size()`. The check should be `if (eventlist !=null && eventList.size() > 0)`

Comment: @highfive,@BarCotter,@Sunny:Thanks for your reply .I tried previously with those option but my trigger is not getting fired still.Dont Know were im loosing the loop .I shall appreciate your help.

Comment: Check the trigger to make sure the Status is Active

Comment: @BarCotter:The Status is Active

Comment: is the `eventlist!==null` in your code a typo? I assume you have changed it to `eventlist != null` and the trigger is still not firing?

Comment: Why are you checking for BOTH a size greater than 0 and a not-null?  By definition, if the list is not empty, it's not null.  I'd check one or the other (probably the not-empty check) and go from there.  I'm assuming the issue is that the empty list is not evaluating.  In addition, you could put a debug or assert call into a test class, and verify that 1) You've actually added a valid record to the list, and 2) that the IF statement is validating correctly.

Comment: One additional question:  Are all of your datatypes appropriate?  For example, is tucObj.Start_Date__c a Date/Time field?  There could be an error in the for loop trying to build the record before it actually exits the loop?

Comment: Have you tried to look at a debug log?  I am guessing we'd be able to help you more if you could put the relevant debug logs here.

Comment: You say the trigger is not getting fired, is that really the case or is it just not doing what you want it to?? There is a difference. Also, post portion of debug logs for the trigger and that will help out a lot

Answer (score 1):

As other's have pointed out, you need to check for NULL before checking size b/c you'll get an NPE when you check size (so the if condition would be:
if (eventList != null && eventList.size() > 0).  Salesforce does short-circuiting on boolean evaluation so it exists immediately if eventList is null.

Having said that, you don't actually need to check for null or empty - just do the insert and if the list is empty, nothing happens, and it will never be null b/c you initialized it in the 2nd line.

Answer (score 0):

Your final `if` condition is the problem. AFAIK actually you no need this check point when you are performing a DML since salesforce is handling it for us. Unfortunately I can't find where I read this (found it from this forum). But you can surround the `insert` statement with a try catch block as a good practice. So just remove your condition and retry the code as below.

```
trigger CreateEvent on TUC__c(after insert){
   List<Event> eventList = new List<Event>();
   for(TUC__c tucObj : Trigger.new){
      Event event = new Event();
      event.whatid  = tucObj.Account_Related__c;  
      event.Subject = tucObj.subject__c;
      event.OwnerId = tucObj.CreatedById;
      event.StartDateTime = tucObj.Start_Date__c;
      event.EndDateTime=tucObj.End_Date__c;
      eventList.add(event);
   }
   try{
      insert eventList;
   }
   catch(DmlException e){
       //your exception handling here
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you are Checking list is empty or not use isEmpty() method instead of using null.....

Retry the code as below.....

```
trigger CreateEvent on TUC__c(after insert){
   List<Event> eventList = new List<Event>();
   for(TUC__c tucObj : Trigger.new){
      Event event = new Event();
      event.whatid  = tucObj.Account_Related__c;  
      event.Subject = tucObj.subject__c;
      event.OwnerId = tucObj.CreatedById;
      event.StartDateTime = tucObj.Start_Date__c;
      event.EndDateTime=tucObj.End_Date__c;
      eventList.add(event);
   }
   if(eventList.size()>0 && !eventlist.isEmpty()){
      insert eventList;
   }
}
```

Comment: You shouldn't need the **eventList.size()** > 0 if you are using **!eventlist.isEmpty()**.  It's a bit redundant.

Comment: Always use **isEmpty()** for checking the emptiness of the list, set or map since usage of **list.size() > 0** consumes more CPU time, consequently the performance of the trigger or apex code is affected.

Comment: @PankajGanwani - one can dispense with the test for empty lists altogether - the `insert eventlist` will do nothing with an empty list and doesn't consume a DML statement

Answer (score 0):

I think this trigger will solve the problem for you.

```
 trigger CreateEvent on TUC__c(after insert){
  List<Event> eventList = new List<Event>();
  for(TUC__c tucObj : Trigger.new){
   Event event = new Event();
   event.whatid  = tucObj.Account_Related__c;  
   event.Subject = tucObj.subject__c;
   event.OwnerId = tucObj.CreatedById;
   event.StartDateTime = tucObj.Start_Date__c;
   event.EndDateTime=tucObj.End_Date__c;
   eventList.add(event);
  }
   if(!eventList.isEmpty()){
    insert eventList;
   }
 }
```

Answer (score -1):

Please try below code.

```
      trigger CreateEvent on TUC__c(after insert){
      List<Event> eventList = new List<Event>();
      for(TUC__c tucObj : Trigger.new){
      Event event = new Event();
      event.whatid  = tucObj.Account_Related__c;  
      event.Subject = tucObj.subject__c;
      event.OwnerId = tucObj.CreatedById;
      event.StartDateTime = tucObj.Start_Date__c;
      event.EndDateTime=tucObj.End_Date__c;
      eventList.add(event);
      }
      if(eventList.size()>0){
      insert eventList;
       }
       }
```

Comment: Sunny, limiting an answer to code only may solve an issue but will rarely truly answer the question in regards to what was going wrong. If we aim to teach and share knowledge, please consider that explaining why certain code behaves differently adds a lot of meaning to an answer. (and will likely receive more up-votes).